# Othello game in Tk

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, object-oriented, design-patterns

I've recently reached a milestone for my [Othello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi#Othello) clone. This is my first Python project and the farthest I've come to a full program beyond small scripts and little automations.

I'd love for you to critique and help me to write better code.

Link:
https://github.com/Mcclujdd/othello

Most of my code here: board.py

```
import tkinter as tkr

master = tkr.Tk()
master.geometry("800x800")
frame = tkr.Frame(master)
frame.pack()

canvas = tkr.Canvas(master, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack(expand=tkr.YES, fill=tkr.BOTH)


class Tile:
    is_empty = True

    def __init__(self, coordinate, is_black, tkr_coordinates):
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.color = 'grey'
        self.tkr_coordinates = tkr_coordinates
        # self.tkr_coordinates = [40, 40, 130, 130] #pixel coordinates for x1, y1, x2, y2


board_matrix = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
            8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
            16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
            24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
            32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,
            40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,
            48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,
            56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]

def create_tkr_coordinates(coordinates): # coordinates must be [x1, y1, x2, y2] format

    y1 = coordinates[1]
    y2 = coordinates[3]
    tkr_values = []

    for row in range(8):
        x1 = coordinates[0]
        x2 = coordinates[2]
        for col in range(8):
            tkr_values.append([x1, y1, x2, y2])
            x1 += 90
            x2 += 90
        y1 += 90
        y2 += 90
    return tkr_values



def generateBoardValues():


    board_height = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
    board_width = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')

    board_matrix_assignments = {}  # a1 - h8 to be assigned to tile objects
    index = 0
    tkr_values = create_tkr_coordinates([40, 40, 130, 130])

    for letter in board_height:
        for number in board_width:

            board_matrix_assignments[board_matrix[index]] = Tile(f'{letter+number}', False, tkr_values[index])
            index +=1

    return board_matrix_assignments

def modifyColor(tile, color):
    canvas.itemconfig(tile, fill=color)


def onClick(event):
    tile = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)

    current_color = canvas.itemcget(tile, 'fill')
    if current_color == 'grey':
        color = 'red'
    elif current_color == 'red':
        color = 'blue'
    else:
        color = 'grey'

    modifyColor(tile, color)


def drawBoard(board):

    for tile in board:
        x1 = board.get(tile).tkr_coordinates[0]
        y1 = board.get(tile).tkr_coordinates[1]
        x2 = board.get(tile).tkr_coordinates[2]
        y2 = board.get(tile).tkr_coordinates[3]

        canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=board.get(tile).color)


    canvas.bind('<Button-1>', onClick)

    tkr.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

You've done an excellent job:

- You did a good job partitioning code into functions
- You leveraged code written by others with the import
- Used meaningful names for functions and variables

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Layout

I recommend moving the class and functions to the top, after the `import` statements.
Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the
code (from a human readability standpoint).

You have inconsistent vertical whitespace.  I recommend removing many of the blank lines,
except those separating the class and the functions.

### Commented-out code

Commented-out code just adds clutter, and it should be removed:

```
    # self.tkr_coordinates = [40, 40, 130, 130] #pixel coordinates for x1, y1, x2, y2
```

### Unused code

Unused code should be removed.

In the class:

```
is_empty = True
```

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few more.

In the class: `is_black`.

In the `create_tkr_coordinates` function, variables `row` and `col`
can be replaced with `_`:

```
for _ in range(8):

    for _ in range(8):
```

### Simpler

Since `board_matrix` is a list of integers 0 to 63, it is simpler
to generate these values with `range` than it is to list all 64:

```
board_matrix = range(64)
```

### Documentation

You should add documentation to the top of your file to state the purpose
of the code.  The [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008) style guide
recommends that you add docstrings for your methods.

### Enum

Consider making the `color` variable an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) type.